# Showing that an ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-21}]$ is principal

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ideals, principal-ideal-domains

I have $\mathfrak{a}=(5,\sqrt{-21}-2).$
Can anyone tell me why $\mathfrak{a}^2$ is principal? 
I have multiplied the ideals out to obtain 
$$(5, 5\sqrt{-21}-10,-17-4\sqrt{-21}) $$
How does this reduce to a principal ideal?

Comment: The generators you have found are not correct; see my answer.

Comment: Yeah, $5\not\in \mathfrak{a}^2.$

Answer (score 2):

The ideal $\mathfrak{a}^2$ is the ideal generated by the products of the generators of $\mathfrak{a}$, hence
$$\mathfrak{a}^2=(5^2,5(\sqrt{-21}-2),(\sqrt{-21}-2)^2)=(25,-10+5\sqrt{-21},-17-4\sqrt{-21}).$$
The latter two generators are clearly both multiples of $\sqrt{-21}-2$, and the identity
$$-(\sqrt{-21}+2)(\sqrt{-21}-2)=25,$$
shows that the first generator is also a multiple of $\sqrt{-21}-2$.

Comment: You also have to show that $\sqrt{-21}-2$ is in the ideal, of course.

Comment: Just add the last-named three generators, @ThomasAndrews.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks, that is certainly worth making explicit.